# А можно из 2х приложений читать одну и ту же область памяти?

Tags: c#, ipc

Как проще организовать чтение данных из одной и той же области в памяти разными приложениями? И как сберечь эту область от рук garbage collector'а? К примеру чтоб у двух приложений был доступ к памяти на 128 байт для 128 char'ов. И как передать второму приложению размер и указатель на эту самую область? 
Решение бы на Net.core.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files

Comment: >поддерживается .NET Core в 3.1 3.0 2.2 2.1 2.0 1.1 1.0

Comment: Лол. Всё так просто. Я когда доразберусь что к чему развёрнуто отвечу на собственный вопрос. Спасиб